# Asx stream on Android

Tags: android, streaming, asx

I have a requirement of playing a Asx stream through an Android application

I have read the Android documentation, and they don't seem to support Windows Media streams

Is there any workaround possible? Has anyone did that before? If yes, is there some source code available? Or a library that implements this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you worried about asx file only or any possible outcome after this?

The asx file can be readable as simple string, read the file using byte array and you can get one or many urls that can be

1. pls file
2. m3u file
3. mp3 url
4. wma url

We don't have to worry about 1,2 and 3. 1 and 2 can have different parsing logics but at the end they will give 3 [mp3 url] and an mp3 url can be easily handled by `MediaPlayer` api in android . but 4 is also difficult work to be done.

Comment: Well 4th is one that is required :-(

Any possible solutions for that?

Comment: find how to play wma code, what i know is you will need libffmpeg and libmms library, need to work on ndk, c coding etc etc....... I haven't done it yet... I just have heard about it....